# No module found DSC extension on Azure Json

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc, azure-rm-template

I am trying to run a DSC file during an installation, and it was working yesterday and tday I'm getting the error below:

```
       "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'IIS2'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: An error occurred while executing script or module 'configuration':  
The specified module 'configuration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory..\nPlease correct the input and retry executing the extension.\"."
```

I don't think anyone has messed with it, but I've spent hours trying to work out what the issue could be, was hoping to get some ideas, if anyoe can see anything I might have missed.

The DSC file is:

```
configuration IIS2
    {

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xActiveDirectory, xStorage, xNetworking, PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xPendingReboot, xDnsServer

        Node localhost
        {
            LocalConfigurationManager
            {
                RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
            }

            xWaitforDisk Disk2
            {
                DiskId = 2
                RetryIntervalSec =$RetryIntervalSec
                RetryCount = $RetryCount
            }

            xDisk ADDataDisk {
                DiskId = 2
                DriveLetter = "F"
                DependsOn = "[xWaitForDisk]Disk2"
            }

            WindowsFeature Failover-Clustering
            {
                Ensure = "Present"
                Name = "Failover-Clustering"
            }

            WindowsFeature Web-Server
            {
                Ensure = "Present"
                Name = "Web-Server"
            }

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what its saying you are calling it as `configuration` and its actually called `IIS2` (I mean from the ARM Template).

```
{
    "name": "System_PowerShell_DSC",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "configuration": {
                "url": "url",
                "script": "file-name.ps1",
                "function": "function-name" # IIS2 in your case
            }
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "configurationArguments": {
                "sfCert": {
                    "userName": "yyy",
                    "password": "xxx"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the DSC configuration from the ARM template and the parameter file are in this link, but they seem correct, or am i mistaken    https://pastebin.com/embed_js/E7Yv4aY4

Comment: check proper way to define dsc extension

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat, could I just ask if I had two configurations, "configuration IIS2" and "configuration IIS3"  do I just change the `"function": "function-name"` .. thanks again for your help :)

Comment: yeah, you would just target the other configuration in the template

Comment: @4c74356b41 King of ARM Template section :-)